# Translate label of Comment Body with String Override

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, string-overrides

I'm using i18n and string overrides for translating fields in the front end. I opened up the comment-section for several content types and it's working great. The only thing is: I can't find a way to translate "Comment" to german to "Kommentar".

I just found out, that the Comment-Form doesn't get a specific language-tag. So it is und(efined) which leads to the english word Comment.

The easiest but a little dirty way to fix that is to translate it by hand with the hook_alter_form in the template.php

Is there a more cleaner way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Please, can you explain more clearly what do you want to translate, dynamic comment body or static label "Comment"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is you should try out
[Localization client](http://drupal.org/project/l10n_client)

This would help you out, and translate the content in t()

Comment: I don't know if that module fixed it, but I found out, that there was no translation for the fields label in the language-section... So I went to admin/config/regional/translate/translate and added the translation. Anyway thanks for the help :)